# Google location api doesnot work in android 6.0.1 if GPS is turned on just recently

Tags: android, android-location, google-location-services

Timeout is called if LocationServices(GPS/WIFI/MOBILE DATA) is turned on Recently, but starts working after some delay.
Google api client gets created ,on connected gets called but it doesnot return any location.

Following code was used in onConnected and build google API :-

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

```
LogConfig.logd(TAG, "buildGoogleApiClient()");
if(mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
else
{
}
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

}

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

```
LogConfig.logd(TAG,"onConnected");
//Check location permission if it is granted by user or not
int hasLocationAccessPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AnalyticsApplication.mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
if (hasLocationAccessPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (mIsGetLastLocationRequest) {
        mIsGetLastLocationRequest = false;
        LogConfig.logd(TAG, "last Location Request");
        try {
            Location loc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (loc != null) {
                LogConfig.logd(TAG, "GotGPSFix:onConnected::" + loc.getLatitude() + "::" + loc.getLongitude());
                updateLocation(loc);
            } else {
                if (mLocRequest == null) {
                    mLocRequest = new LocationRequest();
                }
                try {
                    mLocRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
                    gpsTimeoutValue = TIMEOUT_COARSE_LOCATION_FIX;
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocRequest, this);
                    startGpsTimeoutListener();
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers(LOCATION_RESULT_INVALID);
                    LogConfig.loge(TAG, "Exception: getLastLocation(): requestLocationUpdates" + exp);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogConfig.loge(TAG, "Exception: getLastLocation()" + e);
            if (mLocRequest == null) {
                mLocRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                mLocRequest = new LocationRequest();
            }
            try {
                mLocRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
                gpsTimeoutValue = TIMEOUT_COARSE_LOCATION_FIX;
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocRequest, this);
                startGpsTimeoutListener();
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(LOCATION_RESULT_INVALID);
                LogConfig.loge(TAG, "Exception: getLastLocation(): requestLocationUpdates" + exp);
            }
        }
    }  else {
        LogConfig.logd(TAG, "Request for Fresh Location.");
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocRequest, this);
            startGpsTimeoutListener();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(LOCATION_RESULT_TIMEOUT);
            LogConfig.loge(TAG, "Exception: Request for Fresh Location" + exp);
        }
    }
}
```

}